# Is it possible to get map reduce progress notifications in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Map Reduce is slow in Mongo. That is a given. So, I am wondering if it is possible to receive map reduce progress notifications.

Thanks.

Comment: The solution is to not use map-reduce. MR in MongoDB is badly designed and the implementation is broken-by-design. If you really need a reliable MR implementation: use MongoDB together with Hadoop - otherwise don't use it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am using Windows 7 for my development. Does it mean I must have Cygwin + OpenSSH to be able to run Hadoop? Is Hadoop the only viable alternative for Mongo MR engine?

Comment: Hadoop is an extra layer of complexity to your app, it requires its own servers, connector to Mongo (which from reading user group can be very dodgy at times) and is n ot actually as built in as MR. You are basically looking at a completely new distributed MR engine for what is probably a simple MR just running over a lot of data.

Comment: In fact to contradict @Maulwurfn what I consider the right answer to be either to structure your data and app in such a manner you don't require MRs ever or try out the new aggregation framework or use a pre-built service for external MRs like MongoHQ and MongoLabs does. There is no need to run your own hadoop cluster for a MR...that's overkill

Answer (score 10):

I don't know about any built-in features. You could, however, in a separate script run `db.currentOp()` every once in a while, read map-reduce progress and notify concerned parties.

This is an example of what I can see:

```
> db.currentOp()
{
    "inprog" : [
        {
            "opid" : 249198781,
            "active" : true,
            "lockType" : "read",
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "secs_running" : 14,
            "op" : "query",
            "ns" : "mydb.mycoll",
            "query" : {
                "mapreduce" : "mycoll",
                "map" : function cf__9__f_() {
    emit(this.aid, 1);
},
                "reduce" : function cf__10__f_(k, vals) {
    var result = 0;
    vals.forEach(function (v) {result += v;});
    return result;
},
                "out" : {
                    "inline" : 1
                }
            },
            "client" : "127.0.0.1:44254",
            "desc" : "conn",
            "threadId" : "0x7e98f24e4700",
            "connectionId" : 1958947,
            "msg" : "m/r: (1/3) emit phase 644165/7670157 8%",
            "progress" : {
                "done" : 644165,
                "total" : 7670157
            },
            "numYields" : 644
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: With the additional that there is no way to check the progress out of 100 only that it is still running.

Comment: Wow I wonder how it does that? I mean 10gen themselves said there was no way of doing it sicne there is no way of truely understanding the progress of a js function....gotta look into that. Mind you it does know how many rows went in, but still it doesnt know how many should come out....hmmm