# View progress of long running mongodb aggregation job

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a long running job using Mongodb's (`2.6.0-rc2`) aggregation framework: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/

I have written the aggregation in javascript and run the job as a script
(i.e. `mongo localhost:27017/test myjsfile.js`).
After starting the script, is there any way to see the progress of the job?

For example, using the sample aggregation job:

```
db.zipcodes.aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id: "$state",
        totalPop: {$sum: "$pop"}
    }},
    {$match: {totalPop: {$gte: 10*1000*1000 }}}
])
```

I would like to see that the job is currently performing a group and is 70% done.

For mongo's map reduce jobs, you can view progress via `db.currentOp()`, which has a progress field that shows the percentage of the job that is complete, as outlined in this post:

> [Is it possible to get map reduce progress notifications in mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956942/is-it-possible-to-get-map-reduce-progress-notifications-in-mongo)

Is there anything similar for aggregate?

Answer (score 4):

If you use the [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) aggregation pipeline operator to output the result of the aggregation to another (or [the same](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#replace-existing-collection)) collection, you can open a new mongo shell and see how many documents are in the new collection. If you're overwriting the collection you're aggregating from, MongoDB will use a temporary collection name in order to make the operation atomic, like `tmp.agg_out.1`. So, run

```
db['tmp.agg_out.1'].count()
```

To find out the exact name of the temporary collection, you can tail the current MongoDB [log](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/) and watch for messages about the aggregation. mLab and other cloud MongoDB hosting providers may have a handy "stream current log" option as well.

For example, while running the query in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33374947/insert-field-with-array-size-in-mongo/55532576#55532576), the relevant log messages may look like this:

> 2019-04-05T03:55:42.126-0700 I COMMAND  [conn244209] command **collection.tmp.agg_out.1** appName: "MongoDB Shell" command: insert { insert: "tmp.agg_out.1", ordered: true, $db: "mydb" } ninserted:18145 keysInserted:351002 numYields:0 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 70917, w: 61737 } }, Database: { ... }, Collection: { ... }, Metadata: { ... }, oplog: { ... } protocol:op_msg 161451ms

(I was hoping that [nInserted](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-profiler/index.html#system.profile.ninserted) or [keysInserted](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-profiler/index.html#system.profile.keysInserted) would indicate progress, but that doesn't seem to be the case; the count of the documents in the temporary collection was a much more accurate progress indicator.)

Answer (score 3):

try db.currentOp() will return  in-progress operations for the database instance

for details http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.currentOp/

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question. `currentOp` does not show the progress for `aggregate` operations.