# Insert field with array size in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a documents in mongodb, containing some array. Now I need to have a field containing a quantity of items of this array. So I need to update documents adding this field.
Simply I thought this will work:

```
db.myDocument.update({
     "itemsTotal": {
         $exists: false
     },
     "items": {
         $exists: true
     }
 }, {
     $set: {
         itemsTotal: {
             $size: "$items"
         }
     }
 }, {
 multi: true
 })
```

But it completes with "not okForStorage". 
Also I tried to make an aggregation, but it throws exception:

```
"errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$size'",
"code" : 15999,
"ok" : 0
```

What is a best solution and what I do wrong? I'm starting to think about writing java tool for calculation totals and updating documents with it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method to [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) your documents and return the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of the items array. After that you will need to loop through your aggregation result using the [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop and [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) the itemTotal field for your document using ["Bulk"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) operation for maximum efficiency.

```js
var bulkOp = db.myDocument.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(); 
var count = 0;

db.myDocument.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "itemsTotal": { "$exists": false } ,
        "items": { "$exists": true }
    }}, 
    { "$project": { "itemsTotal": { "$size": "$items" } } }
]).forEach(function(doc) { 
        bulkOp.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({ 
            "$set": { "itemsTotal": doc.itemsTotal }
        });
        count++;
        if (count % 200 === 0) {
            // Execute per 200 operations and re-init
            bulkOp.execute();
            bulkOp = db.myDocument.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
        }
})

// Clean up queues
if (count > 0) { 
    bulkOp.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could initialise a **[`Bulk()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk)** operations builder to update the document in a loop as follows:

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),   
    count = 0;

db.collection.find("itemsTotal": { "$exists": false },
     "items": {
         $exists: true
     }
).forEach(function(doc) { 
    var items_size = doc.items.length;
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({ 
        "$set": { "itemsTotal": items_size }
    });
    count++;
    if (count % 100 == 0) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
});

if (count % 100 != 0) { bulk.execute(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is much easier starting with MongoDB v3.4, which introduced the [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) aggregation pipeline operator. We'll also use the [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator to output the result of the aggregation to the same collection ([replacing the existing collection is atomic](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#replace-existing-collection)).

```js
db.myDocuments.aggregate( [
  {
    $addFields: {
      itemsTotal: { $size: "$items" } ,
    },
  },
  {
    $out: "myDocuments"
  }
] )
```

**WARNING**: this solution requires that *all* documents to have the `items` field. If some documents don't have it, [`aggregate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) will fail with

> "The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing"

You might think you could add a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to the aggregation to filter only documents containing `items`, but that means all documents *not* containing `items` will not be output back to the `myDocuments` collection, so you'll lose those permanently.