# Save length of array in extra MongoDB field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7811259/5403618) answer, I am trying to find out the size of an array and save it in the extra field.

I have a collection `user_details` and the document structure is something like :

```
{
    user_id : 1,
    likes : [1,2,3,4],
    likes_count : 0
}
```

The query I'm using is as follows :

```
db.user_details.update({user_id : 1},{$set:{ likes_count : this.likes.length }})
```

BUT, it throws error that

```
"message" : "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
```

How do I save the length of an array in extra field?

PS: I'm using MongoDB 3.4

Comment: Duplicate of [Insert field with array size in mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33374947/insert-field-with-array-size-in-mongo/55532576)

Answer (score 4):

With MongoDB 3.4 and newer, you can use the **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** pipeline to add the desired field (**[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** stage is equivalent to a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** stage that explicitly specifies all existing fields in the input documents and adds the new fields) and then write the result of the aggregate operation to the same collection using **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out)** operator, thereby effectively updating the underlying collection.

If the collection specified by the **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out)** operation already exists, then upon completion of the aggregation, the **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out)** stage atomically replaces the existing collection with the new results collection.

To get the count, use the **[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size)** operator which returns the length of an array field. **Bear in mind that all documents must have the `likes` field.**

Overall, you need to run the following pipeline to achieve the desired update operation:

```
db.user_details.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": { "likes_count": { "$size": "$likes" } } },
    { "$out": "user_details" }
])
```

Comment: Good to mention that [all documents must have the `likes` field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33374947/insert-field-with-array-size-in-mongo/55532576#55532576).

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size

```
db.users.aggregate(
   [
      {
         $project: {
            likes_count: { $size: "$test" }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

store the returned `likes_count` in an `variable` and perform update by providing the `likes_count` variable

something like this

```
Model.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
                likes_count: { $size: "$test" }
            }
        }
    ], (err, re) => {
        console.log(err, re);
        var likes_count = re[0].likes_count;
        Model.update({email: 1}, {$set: {likes_count: likes_count}}, (err, d) => {
            console.log(err, d);
        })
    }
)
```