# How to determine if mongo aggregation is finished if run via Mongo driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Let's assume that I am using mongo's node.js driver (version 3.2) and I have the following code:

```
async function runAggregation(db) {
  const cursor = db.collection('test1')
    .aggregate([
      // ...
      {
        $out: 'test2',
      },
    ]);
  await cursor.toArray();
}
```

Since the last stage of the pipeline is `$out`, the `cursor.toArray()` promise will eventually resolve to `[]` so it's not very useful. **I am wondering if it is guaranteed that when this promise is resolved, the aggregation will be completed.**

Basic experimentation shows that this is indeed the case but I cannot find any statement in the documentation, that would support this hypothesis.

A similar question has already been asked here:

[View progress of long running mongodb aggregation job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725814/view-progress-of-long-running-mongodb-aggregation-job)

but it's only targeting mongo shell, so the context is a little bit different.

Comment: `Collection.aggregate` either returns [null or cursor](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#aggregate), so it will return when the pipeline has finished processing. Since the `toArray()` method depends on exhausting the cursor, I believe you are correct that the `await` there will be resolved following the conclusion of the aggregation.